# What are the Hokkienese lyrics in the Wax Chattels song "Cede"?

Tags: lyrics

I was reading a review of the new album *Clot* by Wax Chattels. There was one sentence that caught my attention:

> The vitriolic choruses of "Cede" are in Cheng's native language — Taiwanese Hokkien — and are an indignant confrontation about Cross-Strait relations and self-determination.

The [song is available on Bandcamp](https://waxchattels.bandcamp.com/track/cede) to stream, but there aren't any lyrics. And the [Genius page for their album](https://genius.com/albums/Wax-chattels/Clot) says:

> Cede Lyrics (Missing Lyrics)

I tried listening by ear but I can't tell what's English and what's not.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lyrics can be found as subtitles on the bottom of their [music video](https://youtu.be/XVrAxBXbavg) for the song. It's a funny mix of Australian English spellings and traditional Chinese writings, so I've kept it as it is written in the video. I'm just not sure if the Chinese matches up 100% to the Hokkien because sometimes formal writing is used in places of colloquial readings.

> Your
> lies
> are
> not my life
>
> your
> censorship
> isn't
> ownership
>
> 我是誰呢
> 你不知道
> 胡作非為
> 你的宣傳
> 我的身份
> 我的事情
> 我的國旗
> 我的決定
>
> Labour
> camps
> soft
> power
> hiding
> history
> your money reeks
>
> 我有尊嚴
> 我有本錢
> 我會成功
> 我會成功
>
> 我是誰呢
> 你不知道
> 胡作非為
> 你的宣傳
> 我的身份
> 我的事情
> 我的國旗
> 我的決定

Comment: What is the standard for "the Chinese matches up 100% to the Hokkien"?

Comment: @000 I'm not very familiar with written Hokkien; but I do know that characters like「的」can be controversial when writing「ê」. Maybe someone with more knowledge could comment on whether the characters transcribed here match up to the actual Hokkien pronunciations. I would also expect 不 to be 毋. 知道 also might be a bit too Standard by my understanding.